# Try to upload an image using php

Tags: php

I got this error log:
`move_uploaded_file() enter code here [<a href='function.move-uploaded-file'>function.move-uploaded-file</a>]: Unable to move '/tmp/phpGmUpFW' to 'images/test@yahsoo.com.jpg' in enter code here`[..]`send.php on line 32`

also error log

```
`include(user_agent.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/[irelevent]/Craciun2013/index.php on line 63`
```

line32 states:
`if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file)) {`

Please help.

Comment: Do the folder `./images/` exist and have permission to write to it?

Comment: Yes, I do have images, but I set the file to be sent "imagini"- a different file than images

Comment: Try to create a file in the folder using other file management functions, just to know if thats the issue. It may be that you don't have permission to move files from the `/tmp` folder.

Comment: I don't understand. I don't know if it's a delay, but everytime I create a file in temp and then move it to the folder designed to receive files, all the meanwhile pictures start appearing i the designated folder.I don't understand why.

Comment: I figured it out.Server site, code and patience.
Thanks guys for all ur help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems php (either www-data, apache or whatever user runs it) doesn't have permission on your current path. Have you checked who's the folder owner and what permissions does it have?

Comment: where do the 9's come from in permissions?

Comment: 777 - permission now; 930 924 -owner